# Draggable limited in movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I would like to create a **big** `draggable` element and put it into a smaller container that limits its movement, so 2 of the `draggable` sides must touch the container/container's sides.

I also want that the `draggable` object will be `draggable` from anywhere in the frame, and not only while clicking on the object itself.

I saw that **jQuery** provides a nice `draggable` object:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable

Here is an example I made of what is allowed and what is not:

[image: Allowed]

[image: Not Alloed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the containment to that object like following:

```
$(".selector")
             .draggable({ 
               containment: "parent"
             });
```

[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment) is doco